# Can I catch out of memory errors?

Tags: linux, rust

I want to write a safe program, so I will allocate required space in heap at the start of program.

1. Is it possible starting from some point disable heap memory allocation,
   like `toggle_panic_on_heap_allocation`?
2. How can I catch "out of memory" error during initialization? Default behavior is abort, but I would like not crash, just exit with error code?

Comment: What's the difference in panicking (which exits and returns an error code) and "just exit with error code"? Note that OOM should trigger a **panic** (a controlled and orderly exit), not **crash** (forcibly terminated by the OS for doing something bad). Note that the OS OOM killer is outside of your control.

Comment: @Shepmaster At now on oom program (with rust-1.10) prints "fatal runtime error: out of memory\nInvalid instruction" and core dump was created

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot catch out of memory errors.

There's [some discussion](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/could-we-support-unwinding-from-oom-at-least-for-collections/3673) about adding (partial) support, but there are many many issues with catching OOM errors.

What you can do instead is to start a new process and communicate with it through [`ipc-channel`s](https://github.com/servo/ipc-channel). The possibly overallocating process will then simply get killed and the other process can recover from that and restart the failed process.

---

You can't disable heap allocations at runtime, but that's not very interesting anyway, since your program would have to abort whenever you heap allocate. Instead you should statically check for no heap allocations. There's some work/talk in clippy to add such a static analysis as a ["restriction"](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy/issues/632#issuecomment-180864117)

Comment: What about custom memory allocator? For example I call `malloc` and check it result, after that I give allocated memory to allocator and it spread it around `struct`s and `trait`s?

Comment: @user1034749: If you have a custom allocator, then yes it is possible. Beware that a number of standard containers, etc... allocate "behind your back" so will trigger the panic.